# Instância do Service nula com @Autowired

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, spring-boot, job

Olá, pessoal. Estou fazendo uma aplicação webservice REST SpringBoot com JAVA. Preciso que um método seja executado de tempos em tempos. Para isso, estou usando Quartz (org.quartz). O método da classe é executada no tempo que eu quero, normalmente. Porém, esse método instancia um controller para executar um método de busca no banco de dados, e esse método de busca não está funcionando.

A classe controller instanciada usa uma interface Service com a annotation @Autowired. Quando tento executar algum método do controller que utilize essa interface, dá um erro dizendo que está nula.

Já tentei até fazer a busca no banco diretamente pela classe executada periodicamente, mas acusa que o EntityManager está nulo.

---

StackTrace:

```
2016-01-21 12:59:28.596 ERROR 11284 --- [eduler_Worker-1] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell              : Job mainGroup.mainJob threw an unhandled Exception: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at    br.com.conexaonfe.canais.app.controller.ControladorController.findByAppNServer(ControladorController.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
at br.com.conexaonfe.canais.app.controller.ControladorJob.execute(ControladorJob.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.2.2.jar:na]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.2.2.jar:na]

2016-01-21 12:59:28.596 ERROR 11284 --- [eduler_Worker-1] org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger              : Job (mainGroup.mainJob threw an exception.
```

---

ControladorJob (classe que é executada periodicamente pelo Quartz: http://codepaste.net/xsxkxx

ControladorController (classe controller que falei): http://codepaste.net/szag64

ControladorService (interface Service utilizada pelo controller): http://codepaste.net/b59mn5

ControladorServiceImpl (implementação da interface acima): http://codepaste.net/qv1m27

ControladorRepository (interface do repositório): http://codepaste.net/o8oc69

ControladorRepositoryJpa (implementação da interface acima): http://codepaste.net/9dfhzm

Controlador: http://codepaste.net/wwzmaw

Classe principal da aplicação (ela que inicia o quartz): http://codepaste.net/wohb2n

---

Agradeço desde já!

---

**EDITADO**

Pessoal, consegui achar a solução pesquisando muito. Deixo aqui a solução: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965600/how-do-i-manually-autowire-a-bean-with-spring.

Comment: Como ficou o seu arquivo de configuração do Spring?

Comment: No application.properties só tem configurações do banco de dados. O acesso está funcionando perfeitamente, fiz muitos testes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisei bastante e consegui encontrar a solução e o motivo do problema.

- O motivo:

  > Não é possível instanciar manualmente beans, pois isso é totalmente fora no conceito de IoC.
- A solução:

  > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965600/how-do-i-manually-autowire-a-bean-with-spring

Exemplo do link:

```
B bean = new B();
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean( bean );
factory.initializeBean( bean, "bean" );
```